# Chi-square test and monte carlo simulations

Tags: montecarlo, chi-squared, contingency

I wanted to know whether three variables are related so I run three chi-squared tests on pairs of variables (tables below). As the data doesn't meet the assumption that expected values in each cell should be 5 or more in at least 80% of the cells, I've used monte carlo simulations. Is it correct to do such a thing? Does it "solve" the problem? In that case, is there any authority I can cite? 
Thanks,

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uzWH.png)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW9a9.png)

[Table 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6kWU.png)

Comment: Consider moving this question to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ I think you have a much better chance to get help there

Comment: Furthermore when you include such small tables you could write them in the question or a snapshot of them. I think most people would prefer to be able to understand the complete question without opening links.

Comment: I'll move it. Regarding the tables, I agree. But it turns out I'm not allowed to include a snapshot and I thought writing them could be confusing. thanks